# how to make flexi slider like this demo link: http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=bishop

Tags: jquery-plugins, slider, flexslider

i want to make this slider that contain multiple object in one container.i tried like flexi slider and other jquery slider but end up with nothing.i dont know the exact slider name .any body can let me know which type of slider is this the demo link of the slider is 
demo link :[http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=bishop][1].
please check the slider and let me how what r the code to make such slider
demo link is:http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=bishop

```
<div id="multiple-slide-container" class="slides">
  <h2>Multiple slides example:</h2>
  <div class="triple-slides">
    <div class="item-triple triple-first-one">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="foreground-triple">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="element icon"></div>
          <div class="element title">Michelle</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- the same markup for other itens -->
  </div>
  <div class="triple-slides">
    <div class="item-triple triple-second-one">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="foreground-triple">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="element icon"></div>
          <div class="element title">Nicole</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- the same markup for other itens -->
  </div>
  <div class="triple-slides">
    <div class="item-triple triple-third-one">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="foreground-triple">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="element icon"></div>
          <div class="element title">Fabiana</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- the same markup for other itens -->
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="slide-triple-pagination" class="pager">
  <li>
    <a rel="prev" href="#">&larr; Previous </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a rel="next" href="#">Next &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the site this slider is used:

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: thnak in advance to u sir but i want 5 to 6 different photo frame inside the silder with hover css3 effect like this site here is the link: http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=bishop

Comment: thanks in advance to u sir but i want 5-6 image frame into the slider with css3 hover effect(may be i think it is owl slider)..how can i further proceed to it,according to your refference it slides only one content.plz suggest me how i go further as i have to made exactly that this type of slide with 5-6 image frame with css hover effect.the link for the slider is : http://www.yithemes.com/live/?theme=bishop